# How to get item by hashed CharField in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, sha

I have `Device` model that has a field named `token` that stores a pbkdf2_sha256 hashed string.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.models import Model, CharField

class Device(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=200)
    token = CharField(unique=True, max_length=128)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.token = make_password(self.token)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

for example I have a Device object that it's token is hashed value of `ABCD`. now **question** is if I get `ABCD` from user as raw token, how i can find it's device from database? I tried this:

I hashed the `ABCD` that I got from user with `make_password`, but the new hashed value wasn't as same as the old one that was in db.

also I know that I can get device id from user and then check if user's entered token is same with `check_password` method. but I want only get token from user not device id and token.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "pbkdf2_sha256" is the right algorithm for this case as even to check if password is correct, "check_password" doesn't do a simple string comparison. You need a symetrical algo I think or a simple hash algo for which a simple string comparison will work

Comment: Thanks, what do you suggest for that? I just want to save unique tokens in database in secure way, so I decided to hash them like this way. but I think I'm doing this wrong. maybe I shouldn't hash them and there is a better way for doing that?